# Как зделать fsm в aiogram правилно

Tags: python, aiogram

Вопрос такой , например  мы делаем  тест обычно на уроках прописывают каждый вопрос (включая состояние и хэнлером принимают ответ) если вопросов 10 например  норм но если их например  50 - 70 уже запарно , можно ли автоматизировать это и как покажите на примере пожалуйста, циклом я пытался (состояние почему то не ждало ответа и продолжался вывод остальных вопросов).

Comment: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Спасибо Сергей , благодаря  вашему примеру я много  чего  понял.